# Visual C++ compiler's default options

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can you tell me what are the **__DEFAULT__**, implicit [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28VS.100%29.aspx) for cl.exe and for link.exe when compiling from the command line, like:

```
cl whatever.c
```

Thanks!

**update**: To clarify: I am not interesed in the available command line options, I have even linked them from the question. What I am asking for is a list of implicit, default command line options used when you specify none and compile from the command line.

Comment: Assumption Alert: the default behavior does not always match a command-line option. E.g. the default behavior "disable code analysis" has no command-line option; the only command-line option is `/analyze` (Enable code analysis)

Comment: @MSalters Can you give an alternative example? The one you described can be achieved by passing `/analyze-` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173498.aspx)).

Comment: @JBentley: It was literally the first one I found alphabetically (Probably VS2008 then). There are still such flags, e.g. `/GF`.

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be much information on the actual defaults on microsoft web sites, however Geoff Chappell seems to have done some research into this subject. Here is the link:

http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=studies/msvc/cl/cl/initial.htm&tx=27

As we all know what the documentation says, and what the software actually does, are two different things.

To further answer the question, you can see what options cl passes to the compiler modules c1xx.dll and c2.dll by passing the /Bd option to cl:

```
cl /Bd helloworld.cpp
```

To see the environment variables that the compiler and linker uses type:

```
cl /Be helloworld.cpp
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed! These options work, but it's so strange that I can't find any mention of them in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=msvc-170).

Answer (score 1):

I always just search google for "cl options".
This is the current top hit: [Compiler Command-Line Syntax (C++) [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h(VS.80).aspx)

As is usual for Microsoft documentation, it is a bit haphazard, but it does seem to be complete. When an option is the default setting, that is noted (not in any consistent manner, though.)

Comment: Why can't people differentiate between "available command line options" and "default command line options"? See, when you compile a .c file without specifying compiler options some of them will be turned on by default, implicitly.

Comment: My answer did address that issue, so perhaps it is you who lacks reading comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Check `cl /?` on `link /?` at the command line. I believe that the defaults differ for each version.

Comment: This only lists the available compiler options, not the default compiler options.

Comment: Hmm... I could have sworn that the description mentioned the defaults. I don't have a Windows box here so I can't check right now.